# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cachedir'

Tags: python, installation, import, error-handling

After having installed mglearn, I tried to import it but I get the error:

```
import mglearn
```

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cachedir'
```

How can I resolve this?